# array_search for string with space

Tags: php

I have correctly created an array and have an array item with:

```
$array[2] = "Automotive Repairs and Servicing";
```

I try to do a search on $array for Automotive Repairs and Servicing and it returns false:

```
array_search('Automotive Repairs and Servicing', $array);
```

I found that it returns false because I have a space within the search string, i.e. Automotive(space)Repairs(space)and(space)Servicing.

Does anyone know how I can make my search successfully return the key?
I have tried with space as %20, \n, and   as follows:

```
array_search('Automotive%20Repairs%20and%20Servicing', $array);
array_search('Automotive\nRepairs\nand\nServicing', $array);
array_search('Automotive&nbsp;Repairs&nbsp;and&nbsp;Servicing', $array);
```

I will continue to try and fix this problem and if I solve it I will post my answer.

...Thank you for your answer below. I tried your code and it worked for me too.

My real array is actually constructed of data from a database using mysql query and putting the result straight into the array. So not quite sure where the problem lies now.

...

**My Answer:**

Thank you all for responding and helping me with this problem.

I have found my problem... and I'm extremely **embarrassed**.

Turns out there was a space that I didn't see at the end of the string 'Automotive Repairs and Servicing ' in my database.
I've struck this before, my mysql database just like to mess with my head like this sometimes.

So for anyone else out there that gets their mysql result and sticks it into an array then strikes similar problems to this, make sure that your mysql isn't 'pranking' you with a space (invisible to the human eye) in your data.

I'm going out for a cigarette.

Comment: Your `array_search` works for me .. what version of PHP?

Comment: What made you think it was the spaces? Also, make sure they're spaces.

Answer (score 2):

I'm really seeing no issue in that...

But **here's exactly what I tried** :

```
<?php
$array[0] = "noo";
$array[1] = "DONE";
$array[2] = "Automotive Repairs and Servicing";

$index = array_search('Automotive Repairs and Servicing', $array);

echo "Index = $index";

?>
```

And here's the **output** :

```
Index = 2
```

Comment: Same thing here (http://codepad.org/KEe6Mi0A). Maybe the catch is, if the string is found in the first position (index `0`), it will return `0`, and if it's not found anywhere it will return `FALSE`. Both are falsy values, so if `array_search` is inside an if statement it will fail unless it's in the following format: `if(array_search($str, $array) !== FALSE)`.

Comment: @bfavaretto Well, that would be possible; as many other scenarios would. (The OP doesn't clarify that part; I mean where the `array_search` value is used). The only certain thing is : there is **nothing wrong** with the use of `array_search` per se, whatsoever. :-)

Comment: Well said. I should really stop trying to guess what is *really* wrong with other people's code...

Comment: I see what you mean, your code works for me. There must be a different problem, I was just so sure that it is to do with spaces. Please see my edited question above

Comment: @EmmaP A few questions : 1) Is the array populated the way you showed us (`$array[0]='jjjj'`,etc), 2) HOW do you check that it returns `false`?

Comment: Yes, array is populated with mysql query results by a loop like
<code>$array[$loop_counter] = '$result';</code>
When I echo:
<code>array_search("Automotive Repairs and Servicing",$array);</code>
it would return blank.
if I searched "Butchers" instead it would return the key 4.

Comment: @EmmaP Are you **sure** the `$array` values are **exactly** as they should be? (have you tried a `print_r($array);`?

Comment: Yep I'm sure, this is a snippet of what it prints:
`Array ( [0] => Accommodation Motel, Hotel etc with Restaurant [1] => Accommodation Motel, Hotel etc without Restaurant [2] => Automotive Repairs and Servicing [3] => Butchers [4]`

Comment: I might try the `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: @EmmaP Would you mind doing a test for me? Try `$ex = explode(" ",$array[0]); print_r($ex);` and let me know of the **exact** output...

Comment: Actually, I might try and explode the results where a space occurs and replace the space with another character and then explode again and put the spaces back in... a bit complicated, but if it'll work I'll do it

Comment: Hmm... just tested what you said before, result:

Comment: `Array ( [0] => Automotive [1] => Repairs [2] => and [3] => Servicing )`

Comment: @EmmaP Hmmm... (Unfortunately) there's nothing wrong with that... Let me think...